# How do i stop my discord.js bot from spamming the output

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I'm trying to make a discord bot for my discord server that will respond to people referencing inside jokes, but whenever I have the "christmas checker" on it will repeatedly spam. even if the input isn't part of the RegExp.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth() + 1;

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    const regex1 = message.content.match(new RegExp(/fish in a tube|fish tube|fish in the tube|tube fish|where he goin/i));
    if(regex1) {  
        message.channel.send(`Shut the hell up `+ message.member); 
    }   
    if(message.author.bot) return;
});

client.on('message', message => {
    const regex2 = message.content.match(new RegExp(/merry christmas|its december|/i));
    if(regex2){
        message.channel.send('It ain\'t december yet buddy')
    }
    if(message.author.bot) return;
});
client.login('bot key removed');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second regex `/merry christmas|its december|/i` will match anything because the third alternative has nothing entered. [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/auXhdq/1),  regex101's explanation:

> **1st Alternative** merry christmas
>
> **2nd Alternative** its december
>
> **3rd Alternative** — *null*, matches any position

Try changing it to `/merry christmas|its december/i`.

---

Also, you might want to change your code to only use one message handler. And put your check for a bot at the beginning of the handler, since if it's at the end it doesn't serve any purpose.